# Emails going to junk folder rather than inbox

Tags: sharepoint-online, email

I have a basic workflow where in a just set a few fields with some value and copy that list item to another list and then send the mail. Everything is working fine but when the mail goes out, it goes to junk folder.

Can anyone help regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

Set up in your Outlook that's not Junk e-mail.

1. [Overview of the Junk Email Filter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-the-junk-email-filter-5ae3ea8e-cf41-4fa0-b02a-3b96e21de089)
2. [Sharepoint generated emails going to outlook junk folder](https://seneej.com/2014/01/11/sharepoint-generated-emails-going-to-outlook-junk-folder/)

Comment: Hi Fox, As i am a developer i would want the emails to go to inbox without asking the users to change their junk settings.

Comment: Are you sure all users have this problem? Your e-mail server? Exchange?

Comment: yes all users are facing the same problem

Comment: Look I added a new link "Sharepoint generated emails going to outlook junk folder" why can your messages fall into "Junk Email" in Exchange server.